# my.cnf >> fully change it, having real production data on our DB

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, config, my.cnf

Good morning.

I've a MariaDB environtment, with a very basic **my.cnf** on it. Coming by default on product installation:

[image]

We've been working with this configuration from the beggining. So we have real productive data for a year long, on our DB.

If I substitute this my.cnf, by this one here:

https://gist.github.com/fevangelou/fb72f36bbe333e059b66

which is close to our instance specs (VM, quad-core 2.20Ghz, 8GB RAM), adapting it accordingly, **do I have risk to corrupt, break, lose or dirtying existing data in any sense or meaning on DB**? I mean, block size changes, buffer changes, etc. Is it dangerous?

In my case, we have this MariaDB on a WINDOWS instance Server 2k16 edition. So I would've to adapt this optimized config file. Then I should ask you too, **do you have a basic/recommended optimized my.cnf file for Windows, like the one adove or so?**

Thanks and regards.

Comment: It is not by default on product installation . And it is not my.cnf, but my.ini.  By default, it adds innodb-buffer-pool-size to 1/4 of the available RAM

Comment: If you replace yours as-is with Linux my.cnf, it won't start , due to the use  of Linux paths.